# How can I send and receive MMS messages in the background?

Tags: java, android, mms

How can I send and receive MMS messages in the background?

Hi, I'd like to synchronize my application (Android Studio/java) on two phones with MMS, but I don't know how to do it. I'd like to understand how to do it step by step.
Who can help me?
I'm a bit lost with all the interfaces we need and who does what.

Thanks for your help

I send and receive text messages but that's not what I want because it's short, and I want to send a picture.
I'm not very good at networking.